# Single regulator to power mixed signal PCB?

Tags: digital-logic, analog, pcb-design

I have a codec (ADC & DAC) with both analog and digital power and ground connections (upper half is analog, lower half is digital). By placing the device package in such a way that all digital traces are routed under its center and all analog traces are routed above its center I should get a proper layout. My question is how can I power the entire board using a single regulator? Placing it on either parts of the board (above the analog ground part or above the digital ground part) would cause power traces leading to the analog section to cross digital ground or vica versa.

What is the best practice here?

Comment: It depends on your noise requirements, frequencies, currents/power and a lot of other things. What kind of analog signal you have there?

Comment: @Kamil - it's audio freq.

Comment: Put the connection point betwee AGND and DGND right at the regulator, maybe?

Comment: @ThePhoton I was thinking about it but seems uncommon in these types of boards. Don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

So I've always followed this [advice](https://www.sigcon.com/Pubs/edn/adcgrounding.htm), for all sensitive analog sections of a design.   AGND and DGND tied at a single point together under the ADC, codec, etc.   For a recent high gain, hi-fidelity audio board I just necked down the GND plan under my ADC.  The connection is about 100 mil wide, and 10 mil long.  I've got an MCU and DSP on one side and my ADC on the other and no noise issues to speak of.

[image]

My power comes from a single regulator and the analog supply is a filtered version of the digital supply.  In my case it's LC but could be ferrite.  If I had just a few analog pins I would just filter at the pins, but I had a lot of analog circuitry so I have a separate analog plane connected to digital with a filter.

I also like to think about where my return currents will be flowing and try to arrange things so I don't have any digital current flowing near my analog ADC pins.  This was all done with a 4 layer board, and of course no signals ever cross a split in either plane :)

Comment: If I want to use a similar technique on a 2 layer board, how do I connect and where do I place the single regulator? What happens to the ground(s) under the power traces?